# Plot Final Decision Tree from Stacked Caret Model

Tags: r, r-caret

I would like to plot the decision tree from the final stacked caret ensemble model.

I have ran a stacked ensemble using caret.  My level 2 is an `rplot` in which I have the final test model and prediction piece built.  But, I do not know how to build the actual decision tree plot based on this model.

my final test model is:

```
test_model <- train(blenderData[,predictors], blenderData[,labelName],
                     method='rpart', trControl=myControl)

preds <- predict(object=test_model, testingData[,predictors])
```

From this I can calculate the area under the curve but I want to actually plot the decision tree.  I do not know how to do that.  Can anyone help?  I am very new to this.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `visNetwork` package :

```
library(visNetwork)
library(caret)

test_model <- train(iris[,1:4], iris[,5],
                     method='rpart')

visTree( test_model$finalModel)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCZyG.png)